# Fitting data to unknown curve -- Possible tanh

Tags: curve-fitting

I am trying to fit the following dataset:

```
0.01    3.69470157 
0.59744 3.514991345
0.65171 3.265043489
0.70076 2.978933734
0.75021 2.700637918
0.80103 2.413791532
0.84878 2.086939551
0.89572 1.819489189
0.94717 1.532756131
0.99626 1.244667864
1.01643 1.130430784
1.03626 1.024324017
1.05633 0.910153046
1.07605 0.804981232
1.09791 0.708171108
1.11795 0.612456485
1.13841 0.516217721
1.15944 0.421844141
1.18032 0.335218393
1.20003 0.258073446
1.22204 0.181296813
1.24223 0.115157866
1.25935 0.069310744
```

Where the first column is x and the second is y.

I have tried a tanh function, polynomials, and now trying the erf function. Nothing seems to fit correctly.

Is there a way to know what function I should be fitting to this? And if so, what is the form of such a function. Thank you.

BIG EDIT: the function must be monotonically decreases as x increases, and have asymptotic behavior at the tail ends. So for the data-set it looks like it should approach ~3.7 and ~0.0

Comment: If you have access to matlab you can use it's polyfit and polyval functions to help you fit the points to a polynomial. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

Comment: A third order polynomial (cubic) equation does give a fit very similar to the sine equation in my answer, good call. I plotted the result on the same scale I used and the plots appear nearly identical.

Comment: See my edit.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A simple sine(radians) equation with an offset gives a good fit:

```
y = amplitude * sin(pi * (x - center) / width) + Offset

amplitude = -2.2364202059901910E+00
center =  8.6047683705837374E-01
width =  1.1558269132014631E+00
Offset =  2.0456549443735259E+00
```

R-squared: 0.99994

RMSE: 0.00909

[image: sine]

Comment: @KillaKem suggestion to try a polynomial was good: a third order polynomial (cubic) fits the data well and the plot is very similar to the one in this answer.

Comment: I should mention that it should have asymptotic behavior at the ends, such as tanh

Comment: Do you have any additional data to characterize this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. It does look like a tanh function though, just haven't been able to get a good fit yet. Maybe the error function.